# Where is personGroup saved for the face api from MS Cognitive Services?

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I believe I am misunderstanding how this API works...

I understand that Person Groups contain Persons which contain Person Faces.

And to use Face - Verify, I compare the new image FaceId to the personGroupID and personID.

However, I don't seem to understand how/where the Person Groups are saved.

Are all Person Groups saved within one JSON and can be stored in blob storage or a DB?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. using Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PersonGroup [Create API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244) is a little different in that the caller specifies the ID.  Regardless, this ID is stored in the Cognitive Services storage, along with all related information such as the people who comprise this group.  The exact nature of the storage is intentionally opaque.

You can list the PersonGroup's associated with your API key with [List API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395248).

If you're looking for sample code in NodeJS, you can find some [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/project-oxford/blob/master/test/test_face.js#L606).

Comment: Ah right - so to confirm all data (PersonGroups, Persons, Person Faces) are stored on CS storage. And this is not something I can access without calling the API? i.e CS stores this data and I don't have to create a DB/storage system anywhere for it? And this storage is connected to my Face API key?

Comment: And do they thus own this data too?

Comment: The storage is handled by the service, read and write. As for legal rights around use of images, that's a legal matter that I would rather not weigh in on for risk of misinforming you.   You might look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-terms/?cdn=disable)

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot :)